# Given the radius and coordinates of the center of a circle, how do I obtain the pixel median of pixels in the region of the circle?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get the median of a certain region of an image. I have the radius and the center coordinate for that region. How do I find the go about getting all the coordinates of the circle so I can do:

```
np.median(pic[args])
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the median for the given single channel image using a mask, you must first prepare a mask of the same size as the original image as:

```
mask = np.zeros(original_image.shape, np.uint8)
center = (500, 500)
radius = 100

cv2.circle(mask, center, radius, 255, -1)
```

Now you have an engraved circle on the mask with intensity value = 255, now using `np.where` we get the set of x, y index values where `mask==255`, and then access the intensity values using these indices from the original image which returns a single dimensional array of intensity values and using `np.median()` we get the final median value.

```
#this will give you the coordinates of points inside the circle
where = np.where(mask == 255)
intensity_values_from_original = img[where[1], where[0]]
>>> [  9  12  67 ...,  95  95 105]
print np.median(intensity_values_from_original)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's easier to use [numpy.ma.median](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.median.html). To create the mask you can simply use [cv2.circle](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.circle), initialize the matrix with all ones and then draw the circle with zero.

Comment: But that won't give me all the coordinates within the circle.

Comment: np.ma.median gets the image and the mask and returns the median, it's faster than get the coordinates and passing them to np.median, np.ma.median != np.median